# Move div to location in the DOM

Tags: jquery, html

I would like copy & move a `div` ID to another location in the DOM.

```
<div id="portfolio"></div>
```

Is this the right code to implement `.html()`?

```
$(".text").click(function() {
    $("#portfolio").html($(this).next(".text1").html());
    $(this).html('');
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `$("#portfolio").html($(this).html());`? What do you want to achieve with the `.next()`?

Answer (score 2):

To move an HTML element using jQuery, you can use -

```
$("someSelector").appendTo("someOtherSelector");
```

To copy, you can use -

```
$("someSelector").clone().appendTo("someOtherSelector");
```

Have a look here - http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 0):

Use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and then set your content with [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

Working example in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/agconti/aAjbw/

html:

```
<div id="portfolio">stuff</div>
```

js:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#portfolio", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("body").append("<div>" + $("#portfolio").html() + "</div>");
});
});
```

Using `.append()` will add div's after your portfolio element. You can add a div before it by using [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to achieve:

```
$(".text").click(function() {
    $("#portfolio").html($(this));
});
```

.html() refers to innerHtml, or whatever's inside the div, but you're trying to move the object itself.

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Nh9Ef/1/